# Xamarin: Image in ImageView doesn't appear in my Design but appear on AVD?

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview

I have a problem in preview my image in ImageView in Xamarin Visual Studio in the design. However, the image appear on AVD when run the solution on it.
Some screen shots are below.

As you see, I added two images and set the src correctly for them but they doesn't appear in the design:

[image: Image 1]

And when run the code on AVD, all images were appeared:

[image: Image 2]

I want to make the images appear in the design to make whatever changes I need before upload the code on AVD.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches I found the solution on Microsoft site here 
     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613162.aspx

I finally solved the problem.
The problem was solved via update the Xamarin to latest version... Tools > Options > Xamarin > Others and click on "check now" as appear in the image
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl8Bc.png)

If there is a new version it will appear to install.
All thing go right After installing the latest version.